# Middle mouse button in 18.04.2 does not work

Tags: mouse

Middle mouse button in 18.04.2 does not work. I want it to open new tabs in Firefox. Firefox setting regarding this seem to be correct. I tried the XInput trick of setting middle mouse emulation to 1, but it had no effect.

Comment: its critical to mention where your cursor is when issuing this mouse middle button action ... please update your question